How/where to add covariates in SEM mediation model (lavaan)?
Say I have a predictor X, a mediator M, and an outcome Y. I also have a covariate W1 that I assume to have a direct effect on X and M (based on conceptual closeness and empirical findings) but not directly on Y. I want to test my model using the SEM function in lavaan (we're only operating on the level of manifest variables, not sure if that's relevant to my question but just in case).
I'm uncertain on how to go about this since I often can't tell if examples I find are really the same case as my model. E.g., I have found a model in Hayes 2022 (Figure 4.1, p. 130) but that seems to be a case of a confounding variable influencing M and Y directly. If that were applicable to my model, I'd figure the model code should look like this
           # direct effect
             Y ~ c*X
           # mediator
             M ~ a*X + W1
             Y ~ b*M + W1
           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)

but my supervisor found it strange and told me to only include W1 in the formula for the direct effect OR include W1 in the formulas for M and X (as in, specifying M ~ a*X + W1 and X ~ W1). Especially the latter approach seems really odd to me and I'm not sure if lavaan would even allow it since then X wouldn't be an independent/exogenous variable anymore. So how should I specify my model?
I also have a second covariate W2 that could be related to all other variables (including W1), though probably the least to Y. The conceptual reason for inclusion is mainly a potential confounding of the relationship between X and M which I think is basically the same case as for W1, so my idea would be to add both covariates in the same place (so if the above code would apply to my model, I'd replace W1 with W1 + W2). Would that be appropriate?

If you think that, based on your theoretical model, W1 should have a direct effect on X and M, then you should specify your model accordingly--as suggested by your supervisor. You are correct that this would make X endogenous. But if this is what your theory predicts, then you should specify the model to be in line with your theory. Same for W2.
